# ArcGIS Pro missing records in attribute table from SQL Server?

Tags: attribute-table, sql-server, arcgis-pro

I created a table to test ArcGIS Pro 2.2.3 with an Azure SQL Server. The structure of the table is simply an OBJECTID, a shape (Point) and a text field. The table contains a set of 2 points with different locations.

I am then loading this table as a Feature Class into a map in ArcGIS Pro. I can see the 2 points and I can select them both from the map view. The issue I have is that **the Attribute Table only lists a single point when listing all records**. Furthermore I get the following behaviour from the Attribute Table:

- If looking at **all records** with **nothing** selected on map: I see **1 record** and caption says "**0 of 1 selected**"
- If looking at **selected records** with **nothing** selected on map: I see **no record** and caption says "**0 of 1 selected**"
- If looking at **all records** with **both** selected on map: I see **1 record** and caption says "**2 of 1 selected**" (*see image below*)
- If looking at **selected records** with **both** selected on map: I see **2 records** and caption says "**2 of 1 selected**"

[image: Example with 2 points selected on map and only 1 shown in Attribute Table]

The table itself was not created by ArcGIS Pro but was defined in SQL as a table with a spatial field using the following code. The database is hosted on an Azure SQL Server:

```
/****** Object:  Table [geotest].[geometry] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [geotest].[geometry](
    [OBJECTID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Shape] [geometry] NULL,
    [col_as_text] [nchar](100) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_geometry] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OBJECTID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO

/****** Object:  Index [FDO_Shape] ******/
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [FDO_Shape] ON [geotest].[geometry]
(
    [Shape]
)USING  GEOMETRY_AUTO_GRID 
WITH (BOUNDING_BOX =(-400, -90, 400, 90), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Comment: Do you get the same results if you drop the spatial index?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall I tried with no spatial index and the results were the exact same

Comment: Given the lack of interaction with this question I'm starting to think it should have been asked on Stackoverflow since it is related with the development of a database. I will post it and see if I get more info...

Comment: If you define a similar table (featureclass) with arcgis pro, then go into SSMS, right click on table and choose Script Table As> Create To> New Query Window, is the SQL code in the script different from the code that you posted?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/53083760/820534

Comment: While I doubt its an "ArcGIS Pro" specific issue, can you verify by doing the same test from ArcMap?

Comment: @KHibma rather than let the bounty on this go to waste in 2 days I'll happily pay it out on a "two short paragraphs answer" along the lines of "to isolate whether this is actually an ArcGIS Pro issue you could run the same test using ArcMap".

Comment: @PolyGeo as suggested I posted an answer detailing the result from the same test in ArcMap.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed in the comments, the same test was conducted in ArcMap (ArcGIS Desktop 10.6) and the behaviour is the exact same when comparing with ArcGIS Pro 2.2.3

The 2 records are shown on the map, only 1 record is shown in the list of records (capture #1 below) unless all records are selected from the map (capture #2).

[image]

[image]